# Verifying bash script inputs

Tags: bash

I'm writing some very simple Bash scripts and I've become a tad bit stuck.

I would like the script I'm attempting to write to be able to differentiate between "non valid inputs ie letters" from "valid inputs ie numbers from a specific range"

Currently the script "works" although I'm having troubles with another echo that I would like only to "echo" when the below line is "not true", is there a simple way to write this? I'm not specifically looking for efficient code, just code that I can learn from and understand at my amateur level.

So, long story short, is it possible to obtain information from the command line below, so that I can have a simple "not true" variable that I can use in another "else" or "elif" command?

For reference line 1 is to detect alphabetical inputs, and line 2 being the line of code I would like to write as "not true" for use in another part of my script.

1. let xx=$a+1-1 2>/dev/null; ret=$?
2. if [ $a -ge 7 ] && [ $a -le 70 ] && [ $xx -eq $xx ] && [ $ret -eq 0 ]

Comment: Always QUOTE YOUR VARIABLES in `[ .. ]` (there is no need in `[[ .. ]]`), but in `[ .. ]` it is mandatory. (`[ .. ]` is an alias for `test`).  To suppress the error when a non-integer is entered for `xx`, you can `[ "$xx" -eq "$xx" 2>/dev/null ]` to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` (the bit-bucket...)

Comment: It worth bookmarking the guides [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)  (especially the Pitfalls `:)` along with [**shellcheck.net**](https://www.shellcheck.net/) Spending a bit of time with the [**Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) is time well spent.

Comment: In addition to the treasure troves of information others have linked, click the `bash` tag under your question,  then click "Learn more..." for the bash tag wiki here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @JB : I would detect input containing an alphabetic character by doing `[[ $a == *[A-Za-z]* ]]`. Checking whether `a` contains *any* nun-numeric character can be done by `[[ $a == *[^0-9]* ]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with the "variable with integer attribute" is that it still doesn't protect you from invalid input:

```sh
$ declare -i aNumber
$ aNumber=1234X
bash: 1234X: value too great for base (error token is "1234X")
```

See [6.5 Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) for how bash interprets values to be numbers (scroll down to the paragraph starting with "Integer constants follow the C language definition")

In my experience, the best way to check for valid numeric input is with string-oriented pattern matching.

```sh
if [[ $1 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "input $1 is an integer"
fi
```

In addition to extended regular expressions, bash's [advanced pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) can also be used within `[[...]]`

```sh
if [[ $1 == ?([+-])+([0-9]) ]]; then
    echo "input $1 is an integer"
fi
```

---

`((...))` is preferred over `let`. See [the let builtin
command](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let) for details.
Also [the shellcheck wiki entry](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2219).

Answer (score 2):

If I read it right:

```
typeset -i xx # accepts only digits now.
```

If the input is foo, the value defaults to 0, so now just check the range.

```
if (( xx >= 7 && xx <= 70 )); then : value is ok
else echo "Value must be a number from 7 to 70"
     exit 1
fi
```

I also recommend the following useful resources: the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) and the [BashFAQs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: NOTE: this method will allow some odd entries to slip through - for example, assigning `xx=0xdeadbeef` will actually store `3735928559`, since it's a valid hex-formatted value...